# What's the difference between mixed effects logit model and mixed logit model?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, random-effects-model, definition

Recently，I'm working on a dataset with binary responses. I come across two models with quite similar names, i.e., mixed-effects logit model and mixed logit model. As far as I know, the mixed-effects logit model includes fixed effect coefficients for each attribute and random effect coefficients for attributes and groups(individuals). While mixed logit model seems to have a similar definition that each individual's coefficient to the attribute is different and assumed to be a random variable.

[image]
They both have a similar unconditional likelihood function.
I am confused by these two models. Can you consider the mixed logit model to be a special case of the mixed effect logit model, which excludes fixed effects and restricts the group to the individual level? Can anyone help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you give references for your use of this term? I would have assumed they denoted the same models.

Comment: I think the use of these terms may vary by applied discipline. I've heard "mixed logit" used to describe a mixed effects logistic regression model, and also as an alternative to a multinomial mixed effects regression model.

Comment: In Wiki, the mixed logit model is a discrete choice model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_logit. While mixed-effects logistic regression model is a kind of Generalized linear mixed model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_mixed_model

Comment: Right. A multinomial mixed effects regression model is a discrete choice model.